# Handling Large No's in Java

Tags: java

I am having trouble with large numbers in java while trying to store them in float variable.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class testConversion {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "135598877.50";

    Float f = Float.parseFloat(s);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.println(df.format(f));

}

}

OUTPUT:

1.3559888E8

135598880.00
```

The output of this program is `135598880.00` and not `135598877.50`.

Why this thing is happening and what is the best way of handling this? I don't want truncation/rounding at all.

Regards,
Kaddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float`s are stored using [IEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  They cannot store large numbers precisely.

As you hinted in the question, you need to use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick Response Everyone. I am moving from float to BigDecimal

Answer (score 1):

Try using Double rather than Float.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Doubler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String        s  = "135598877.50";
        Double        f  = Double.parseDouble(s);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(df.format(f));    
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1.355988775E8
135598877.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had the right idea about using BigDecimal, this works like it should;

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class testConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "135598877.50";

        BigDecimal f = new BigDecimal(s);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(df.format(f));

    }

}
```