# Handling Large Numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bigdecimal

I just moved from `Float` to `BigDecimal` in [my java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029404/handling-large-nos-in-java) because I am dealing with large numbers.
Now i need to figure out how to handle these numbers in my JSP pages where I am using some validations on these numbers. I am currently handling the numbers in javascript in the following way:

```
var largeValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lValue').value);
```

and then I compare `largeValue` to other values.
(lvalue is id of a field where the large value is stored)

i need to know what is the limit of the 'parseFloat' method? and what would be a better way of comparing large numbers in javascript?

Regards,
Kaddy

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it would be the same as the maximum value that a float can store, i.e., `1.7976931348623157e+308` according to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max_value.asp).

Comment: So you mean this will hold true in javascrip also?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029404/handling-large-nos-in-java

Comment: And if yes how should i handle it?

Comment: @Kaddy: Yes, floats will always suffer from that problem in any language. I haven't had any experience with this in JS myself, but perhaps this Q will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library

Comment: The problem isn't just the maximum value but the maximum precision.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, more often it's the precision that's the problem. Decimal classes are specifically good at storing arbitrary precision (or rather you often define the precision needed during construction).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basenumber.js](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js) to handle with comparisons of `BigDecimals` in javascript. It's based on native `BigInt` so is lighter than others libs. Useful to lead with this types of problems:

```
console.log( 0.1 + 0.2 );  // = 0.30000000000000004
```

#### Here an example of how to use it

```js
let x = Base("0.1");

let y = x.add(0.2);

console.log(y.toString());  //   = '0.3'
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```

##### Comparing numbers

```js
let a = 0.99999999999999999999;
let b = 1;

console.log(a == b);       // = true

let x = Base("0.99999999999999999999");
let y = Base("1");

console.log( x.equalTo(y) );   // => false
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```